# Event sourcing a domain with several layers of object composition

Tags: scala, cqrs, event-sourcing

I've been reading lots of great articles on event sourcing and CQRS and the concept is intriguing, but the examples are generally of domains that are ultra-simplistic (e.g. an invoice, a conference event, a set of blog posts and their associated comments).

Say we have a more complex domain like that of an insurance policy where we have a deeper hierarchy of relationships:

```
class Policy {
   List<Driver> drivers
   List<Vehicle> vehicles
   List<Coverage> coverages
}
```

Driver may have addresses and contact information, coverages have sub coverages, etc.

I could create CRUD like events on each one of these objects separately (e.g. DriverCreate, DriverUpdate), but if we wanted to rewind the state of a Policy to a specific date, how would we know which events to rewind?

In general, are there any resources out there that describe how to deal with *relationships* in this development paradigm?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on such a system, even if not for insurances ;-)
The strategy we chose is the following. We've linked our events thanks to identifiers. Your Policy class would have been added a field "id" for this purpose. Once done, it is possible to create events like this :

```
case class PolicyDriverAdded(id: UUID, driver: Driver)
case class PolicyDriverRmoved(id: UUID, driver: Driver)
```

This is the simplest strategy. Another one would be to put the complete collection in your event... twice :

```
case class PolicyDrivesChanged(id: UUID, oldDrivers: List[Driver], newDrivers: List[Driver])
```

This second option is more robust and will let you have the data you need for rewinding.